# BibTex entry does not show up

Tags: bibtex

In the parsed document for the following entry, the name of the journal is not shown. What could be the reason behind it?

```
@InProceedings{Yan_2015_CVPR,
author = {Yan, Junchi and Zhang, Chao and Zha, Hongyuan and Liu, Wei and Yang,    Xiaokang and Chu, Stephen M.},
title = {Discrete Hyper-Graph Matching},
journal = {The IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR)},
month = {June},
year = {2015}
```

J. Yan, C. Zhang, H. Zha, W. Liu, X. Yang, and S. M. Chu. Discrete hyper-     graph matching. June 2015.

Answer (score 2):

An `inproceedings` entry uses the same fields as an `incollection` entry. Keep the`title` field set to the title of the article, and use the `booktitle` field to define the title of the conference.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I wouldn't say that the `@inproceedings` and `@incollection` entry types take the same fields. According to the BibTeX manual itself -- type `texdoc bibtex` at a command prompt -- the `@incollection` entry type has *five* required fields -- `author`,
`title`, `booktitle`, `publisher`, and `year` -- whereas the `@inproceedings` entry type has only `four` -- `author`, `title`, `booktitle`, and `year`. Thus, I'd keep the entry type `@inproceedings` unchanged and switch the name of the field (as in your suggestion) from `journal` to `booktitle`.